# Как полученное рандомное число отправить и получателю и админу telegram bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Создал бота который отправляет рандомное число заказчику.

Помогите пожалуйста как сделать, так что бы это число получал заказчик и админ одновременно.

```
import random

k = 0
while True:
    numG = random.randint(100000, 999999)
    numQ = random.randint(100000, 999999)

    k += 1
    if numQ == numG:
        print("Номер заказа {} ".format(k, numG, numQ))
        break

if text == 'randomly':
    bot.send_message(m.chat.id, "Номер заказа {} ".format(k, numG, numQ))
```

Comment: Админ где находится? Речь идет о посылке сообщений двум пользователям одного бота (админу и еще одному)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить ещё одну строку `bot.send_message(m.chat.id, "Номер заказа {} ".format(k, numG, numQ))`, где вместо `m.chat.id` нужно поставить ид админа. Чтобы узнать айди пользователя, есть много ботов, @userinfobot, например. Так же чтобы бот мог отправлять сообщения, пользователь должен его стартануть (/start)

Comment: Спасибо, огромное! Ценю таких людей)))))